# laptop almost freezes when try to dim screen (nvidia optimus)

Tags: nvidia

I just got a Samsung  NP300E5A notebook with Nvidia Optimus.
Following other answers, I installed Bumblebee and after some troubleshooting (followed https://github.com/Bumblebee-Project/Bumblebee/issues/220) I finally get this:

```
desktop:~$ glxinfo | grep OpenGL
OpenGL vendor string: Tungsten Graphics, Inc
OpenGL renderer string: Mesa DRI Intel(R) Sandybridge Mobile 
OpenGL version string: 3.0 Mesa 8.0.2
OpenGL shading language version string: 1.30
OpenGL extensions:

desktop:~$ optirun glxinfo | grep OpenGL
OpenGL vendor string: NVIDIA Corporation
OpenGL renderer string: GeForce GT 520MX/PCIe/SSE2
OpenGL version string: 4.2.0 NVIDIA 304.37
OpenGL shading language version string: 4.20 NVIDIA via Cg compiler
OpenGL extensions:

optirun glxspheres 
Polygons in scene: 62464
Visual ID of window: 0x21
Context is Direct
OpenGL Renderer: GeForce GT 520MX/PCIe/SSE2
```

It seems OK then, but if I try to dim the screen (or if I go on batteries and it tries to do so automatically) it doesn't seem to be able to do it and almost freezes (eats up so much CPU that I cannot even shutdown properly).

In another forum I saw somebody with the same problem and no help (https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xserver-xorg-video-nv/+question/205823)

Update:
Following this (http://ubuntucomputing.blogspot.com.br/2011/10/how-to-fix-adjust-screen-backlight-of.html#comment-form) I improved it a litle by editing /etc/default/grub for

GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="splash acpi_backlight=vendor"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="acpi_backlight=vendor"

and runing 'update-grub'. However, now I can dim the screen but I cannot get it all the way up again!. Is it perhaps related to something different than bumblebee? (I do not know)

Any idea please please?

Answer (score 1):

Turn off optimus and run discrete graphics only. That seems to work for me using my lenovo W520.

Comment: Thank you. How do I do that definitely? (haven't found it) Now, with bumblebee, I think it is turned off when not used (if I run sudo cat /proc/acpi/bbswitch, I get "0000:01:00.0 OFF"), but I do not know if it gets turned on when I try to modify the brightness.

Answer (score 1):

I found another workaround that works. It is a little script that somebody wrote for Archlinux but works the same:

https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=1148019#p1148019

Before this, I could only dim the screen. Now (using the terminal) I can light it up again :-)) Very happy!

In any case, I would like to know how to "embedd" this in the system, I mean, how can I modify ubuntu brithness control so that it makes the same that the script. Any ideas please?